# I live in the UK but my nationality is Nigerian and I have married an Irish citizen

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit

I married an Irish citizen who works and lives in UK. The marriage had to be approved by the Home Office because I am subject to immigration control due to overstaying a visitor's visa by two years. How long does it take to process my resident permit here in UK?

Comment: Just to clarify, all immigrants into the country are 'subject to immigration control' until such time as they leave, or become citizens. The reason why your marriage received extra scrutiny was strictly because it appeared to be a marriage of convenience to get around immigration laws. They determined it wasn't, and so allowed the marriage to take place. Keep in mind, this does not necessarily grant you any extra special privilidges with regards to obtaining permission to stay in the UK, and you technically still don't have that.

Comment: The laws that come into play here are EU laws. I'll let others answer that.

Comment: @ouflak "subject to immigration control" is a specialized term in the UK.  Foreigners with ILR, for example, are not subject to immigration control, and neither are EU/EEA/Swiss citizens or their family members.  It seems to be roughly equivalent to the distinction between those for whom entering the country is a privilege, and those for whom it is a matter of right.  As the spouse of an EU national in the UK, OP *has* a right to stay in the UK, and is no longer subject to immigration control.  The permit serves as evidence of that right, but the right is independent of the document.